# find the summation for multiple columns and keeping the column name

Tags: python, pandas

Assume we have a dataframe df1 with 45 columns filled with float numbers. It has the following form(for simplicity I will use int numbers in this example)

```
df1

Jan 2023_a   Jan 2023_b  Jan 2023_c  Feb 2023_a Feb 2023_b Feb 2023_c  Mar 2023_a  Mar 2023_b Mar 2023_c  ...
1        2       1      3     2     5     1      2      0    ...
0        3       1      4     0     0     2      1      3
```

I want to create a new columns that add every previous 3 columns(in axis=1) and for a column name it keeps the Month but change the suffix. Like the following

```
df1

Jan 2023_a   Jan 2023_b  Jan 2023_c  Jan 2023_sum   Feb 2023_a Feb 2023_b Feb 2023_c Feb 2023_sum  Mar 2023_a  Mar 2023_b Mar 2023_c  Mar 2023_sum  ...
1        2       1      4          3     2     5     10       1      2      0     3      ...
0        3       6      9          4     0     0      4       2      1      3     6
```

So basically calculate the sum for each month and then place it after the corresponding columns. The tricky part is that the column names are dynamic. Meaning I cannot hardcode the column names since depending on the csv file I read it might start from January or it might start from June etc

EDIT: I updated the column names to also include the year

Comment: Are the column names always separated by "_"? This would make it easier

Comment: Hello. Yes the column names are always separated by _ and it is always followed by a or b or c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
totals = (df.groupby(lambda c: c.split("_")[0], axis="columns").sum()
            .add_suffix("_sum"))
new_df = df.join(totals)
```

- group the frame over columns' values before "_"
- sum the groups, and add the "_sum" suffix (e.g., to get "Feb_sum" etc.)
- join it with the original frame

Example run:

```py
In [135]: df
Out[135]:
   Jan_a  Jan_b  Jan_c  Feb_a  Feb_b  Feb_c  Mar_a  Mar_b  Mar_c
0      1      2      1      3      2      5      1      2      0
1      0      3      1      4      0      0      2      1      3

In [136]: totals
Out[136]:
   Feb_sum  Jan_sum  Mar_sum
0       10        4        3
1        4        4        6

In [137]: new_df
Out[137]:
   Jan_a  Jan_b  Jan_c  Feb_a  Feb_b  Feb_c  Mar_a  Mar_b  Mar_c  Feb_sum  Jan_sum  Mar_sum
0      1      2      1      3      2      5      1      2      0       10        4        3
1      0      3      1      4      0      0      2      1      3        4        4        6
```

We see that the *_sum columns place at the end; to bring them next to their root columns, we can sort the columns with a custom mapping:

```py
months = new_df.columns.str.split("_").str[0]
mapper = {mon: idx for idx, mon in enumerate(months.unique())}
new_df = new_df.sort_index(axis="columns", key=lambda _: months.map(mapper), kind="stable")
```

to get

```py
In [148]: months
Out[148]:
Index(['Jan', 'Jan', 'Jan', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Mar', 'Feb',
       'Jan', 'Mar'],
      dtype='object')

In [149]: mapper
Out[149]: {'Jan': 0, 'Feb': 1, 'Mar': 2}

In [150]: new_df
Out[150]:
   Jan_a  Jan_b  Jan_c  Jan_sum  Feb_a  Feb_b  Feb_c  Feb_sum  Mar_a  Mar_b  Mar_c  Mar_sum
0      1      2      1        4      3      2      5       10      1      2      0        3
1      0      3      1        4      4      0      0        4      2      1      3        6
```

Comment: For some reason for the months after Mar 2023 and after, the order of the column is not correct. Sometimes the total is first, others the order of the columns a,b,c is not correct

Comment: @alexntou11 oh i see i think; can you pass `kind="stable"` to the `sort_index` at the end? Thing is, when 2 values are "equivalent" under the mapping in the sort, their resultant order is not specified. With "stable", we tell it to preserve the original order, so that "a", "b", "c" is not messed up. Updated the answer on that front.

Comment: what happens if I also want to create an empty column before the columns _sum with the suffix _comp?

Comment: @alexntou11 you can do `empties = pd.DataFrame(None, index=df.index, columns=df.columns.str.split("_").str[0].unique()).add_suffix("_comp")` after defining `totals`, and then `new_df = df.join(empties).join(totals)` instead of `df.join(totals)` only. We first join with the `empties` so that they will appear *before* the *_sum columns as the sort is stable.

Comment: but the mapper is not defined before the df.join(totals)

Comment: @alexntou11 yes noticed that, and was updating the comment :) if you refresh the page, it should be fine i think. The mapper.keys() there is the unique prefixes (before "_"), so we don't need the `mapper` anyway.